# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6: /boot/grub/menu.lst or /boot/grub/grub.conf?

Tags: boot, rhel, grub, scientific-linux

I have a brand new Scientific Linux 6 system, but this same question should apply to CentOS 6, RHEL6 or any RHEL6-derivative.

I see that `/boot/grub` contains a `menu.lst` as well as a `grub.conf` file. There is also a symlink from `/etc/grub.conf` to `/boot/grub/grub.conf` which suggests that I should use `grub.conf`.

```
# cd /boot/grub
# ls -ld grub.conf menu.lst
-rw-------  1 root root 845 Aug 29 13:00 grub.conf
-rw-------. 1 root root 847 Aug 29 13:00 menu.lst
# ls -l /etc/grub.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Aug 29 13:00 /etc/grub.conf -> ../boot/grub/grub.conf
```

These files aren't provided by an RPM, which makes it difficult to find a changelog describing this change:

```
# rpm -qa --whatprovides /etc/grub.conf /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/grub.conf 
no package triggers /etc/grub.conf
no package triggers /boot/grub/menu.lst
no package triggers /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Which file should I use? Why are there two files? Can you point me at any authoritative documentation?

**Update** Interestingly, on a RHEL5.6/5.7 system, `menu.lst` is typically a symlink to `./grub.conf`. The symlink from `/etc/grub.conf` is also there:

```
# ls -l /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/grub.conf /etc/grub.conf
-rw------- 1 root root 1036 Aug  2 11:34 /boot/grub/grub.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Apr  5 00:42 /boot/grub/menu.lst -> ./grub.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug  3  2009 /etc/grub.conf -> ../boot/grub/grub.conf
```

But, this symlink is no longer present in RHEL6. I cannot find any documented reason why this would be.

Comment: RHEL6 still follows the same behavior (`menu.lst` being a symlink to `./grub.conf`) by default.  (All my RHEL6 boxes are like that.)  I just dropped SL6 into VM to compare, and I'm still seeing the same setup (`menu.lst` being a symlink to `./grub.conf`) out of the box.  All that to say: what version of grub is on your system (`rpm -q grub`), and did you enable any 3rd party repos, or install any third party software?  I'm wondering if a 3rd party package may have tried to update the bootloader, and inadvertently broke the symlink.  What are the differences between `menu.lst` and `grub.conf`?

Comment: I am running grub-0.97-70.el6.x86_64. The serial console is enabled in `grub.conf`, but is disabled in `menu.lst`. The more I look at this, the more I think this is a bug with SL6.1, or a bug in our buildscripts (But I'm not finding evidence for a bug with my buildscripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should use `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, and `/boot/grub/menu.lst` should be a symlink to `grub.conf`.

These files are initially created by anaconda during the install. This is logged in `/var/log/anaconda.program.log`. We can see that this anaconda execution uses `grub.conf`, not `menu.lst`:

```
13:00:23,089 INFO    : Running... ['/sbin/grub-install', '--just-copy']
13:00:23,134 INFO    : Running... ['/sbin/grub', '--batch', '--no-floppy', '--device-map=/boot/grub/device.map']
13:00:23,346 INFO    : 
13:00:23,347 INFO    : 
13:00:23,347 INFO    :     GNU GRUB  version 0.97  (640K lower / 3072K upper memory)
13:00:23,347 INFO    : 
13:00:23,348 INFO    :  [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.  For the first word, TAB
13:00:23,348 INFO    :    lists possible command completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
13:00:23,348 INFO    :    completions of a device/filename.]
13:00:23,348 INFO    : grub> root (hd0,0)
13:00:23,348 INFO    :  Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
13:00:23,348 INFO    : grub> install --stage2=/boot/grub/stage2 /boot/grub/stage1 d (hd0) /boot/grub/stage2 p (hd0,0)/boot/grub/grub.conf
13:00:23,348 INFO    : grub>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **menu.lst**. I have a scientific linux 6.1 installed and it uses the menu.lst.
You can verify on SL official doc page: http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.1/x86_64/os/repoview/grub.html

Comment: While this is helpful, that page doesn't discuss menu.lst or grub.conf. In addition, the RPM on that page doesn't provide these files either. Apparently they are created by anaconda, which calls `grub-install` (The execution of `grub-install` can be seen in /var/log/anaconda.program.log).

Comment: That page talks about grub 0.97, and, by default, that version of grub uses menu.lst. This can be verified by: `grub --version`. Thank you for helping Stefan. I had not my SL available when I replied to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why Red Hat chooses to use `/boot/grub/grub.conf` as GRUB's configuration file since the GRUB specification is for `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.  I believe the symbolic link is necessary because stage 1 of the boot loader refers to `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.